# Passing Apache variable into SetHandler directive

Tags: apache-2.4, unix, php-fpm, httpd.conf, mod-proxy-fcgi

I'm trying to have **dynamically determined Unix socket** used for different separated PHP "apps" (different sockets lead to different ***PHP-FPM*** pools) on my Apache (2.4.18) server (using ***mod_proxy_fcgi***):

```
<DirectoryMatch "/home/apps/app_(?<appname>[a-zA-Z]+)">

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix://var/run/app_%{env:MATCH_APPNAME}.sock|fcgi://localhost:42001"
    </FilesMatch>

</DirectoryMatch>
```

Unfortunately **Apache doesn't seem to recognize/evaluate the variable** defined by the regular expression match in the **`<DirectoryMatch>`** directive when used with the **SetHandler** directive.

The `error.log` says this:

```
[proxy:error] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/app_%{MATCH_APPNAME}e.sock (*) failed
```

**How would one go about passing a variable to the *SetHandler* directive?** My PHP-FPM is working correctly when I use a "rigid" path to the UDS (eg. `"proxy:unix://var/run/app_someappname.sock|fcgi://localhost:42001"`, but there seems to be a problem when using a variable in it.

---

I also tried building the path using several variables joined together:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    Define one "proxy:unix://var/run/app_"
    Define two ".sock|fcgi://localhost:42001"
    Define final ${one}%{MATCH_APPNAME}e${two}
    Header set HANDLER_PATH ${final}
</FilesMatch>
```

In this case the PHP source is *not* processed by PHP, but the HTTP response header for the URL `http://127.0.0.1/apps/someappname/index.php` (correctly) contains: `HANDLER_PATH: proxy:unix://var/run/app_someappname.sock|fcgi://localhost:42001`

But when I pass the `${final}` variable to **SetHandler**, server returns `503 Service Unavailable` and `error.log` says:

```
*: using default reverse proxy worker for unix://var/run/app_%{MATCH_APPNAME}e.sock|fcgi://localhost:42001/home/apps/app_someappname/www/index.php (no keepalive)
*: rewrite of url due to UDS(/run/app_%{MATCH_APPNAME}e.sock): fcgi://localhost:42001/home/apps/app_someappname/www/index.php (proxy:fcgi://localhost:42001/home/apps/app_someappname/www/index.php)
AH01143: Running scheme unix handler (attempt 0)
AH01076: url: fcgi://localhost:42001/home/apps/app_someappname/www/index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
AH01078: serving URL fcgi://localhost:42001/home/apps/app_someappname/www/index.php
AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
AH00944: connecting fcgi://localhost:42001/home/apps/app_someappname/www/index.php to localhost:42001
AH02545: fcgi: has determined UDS as /run/app_%{MATCH_APPNAME}e.sock
AH00947: connected /home/apps/app_someappname/www/index.php to httpd-UDS:0
(2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/app_%{MATCH_APPNAME}e.sock (*) failed
AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
proxy_util.c(2175): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
```

---

What strikes me is that when the sock's path is being put into HTTP header, it is correctly resolved as 
`proxy:unix://var/run/app_someappname.sock`, but when the variable is passed to **SetHandler**, it suddenly becomes `unix://var/run/app_%{MATCH_APPNAME}e.sock` with a literal `%{MATCH_APPNAME}e`, like if the variable was resolved by the **SetHandler** itself (and incorrectly) ...

**How would one do this?** Is this even possible? I think it must be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried RewriteRule with `[H=` instead of `SetHandler`?

RewriteRule would have the advantage of evaluating arguments when it's executed rather at startup (typical directives do not interpolate per-request variables when they actually execute)

Comment: Oh my, I tried it again and you're right. Thank you so much! For those than would need this: `Define handler proxy:unix://var/run/app_%{env:MATCH_APPNAME}.sock|fcgi://localhost` and then `RewriteRule ^ - [H=${handler}]`

Comment: This might work for misleading reasons. I think define is substituting the literal %{env...} string and startup and mod_rewrite is evaluating it.  So it is a handy way to avoid a massive line for the RewriteRUle but it is not really helping with the evaluation (IIUC)

Comment: Yes, it is true that `RewriteRule ^ - [H=proxy:unix://var/run/app_%{env:MATCH_APPNAME}.sock|fcgi://localhost]` works too.